# how to lookup between two dataframes and update the value in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a dataframe `df1` like below -

```
|email_id| date |
|abc@gmail.com | ['2022-04-09'] |
|ABC@gmail.com | [nan]
|def@gmail.com | ['2022-09-21','2022-03-09'] |
|ghi@gmail.com | [nan, '2022-03-29'] |
|jkl@gmail.com | [nan] |
|mnp@gmail.com | [nan,'2022-09-01']
```

Another df `df2` -

```
|email_id| status |
|abc@gmail.com | 0 |
|def@gmail.com | 0 |
|ghi@gmail.com | 0 |
|mno@gmail.com | 3 |
|pqr@gmail.com | 2 |
|MNP@gmail.com | 1 |
```

How can I lookup email_id from df2 in df1 and update the status in df2?
If we have the date values present in df1 date column , status for that email_id should be 0, and if we have any nan values present, the status should be 1. If some email_id from df2 doesn't match in df1 , will keep the status as same.

Expected output of df2 -

```
|email_id| status |
|abc@gmail.com | 1 |
|def@gmail.com | 0 |
|ghi@gmail.com | 1 |
|mno@gmail.com | 3 |
|pqr@gmail.com | 2 |
|MNP@gmail.com | 1 |
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for column from lists, then create compare for missing values with aggregate `max` for mapping Series, use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace non matched values to original column `df2['status']`:

```
df = df1.explode('date')
s = df['date'].isna().astype(int).groupby(df['email_id'].str.lower()).max()
print (s)
email_id
abc@gmail.com    1
def@gmail.com    0
ghi@gmail.com    1
jkl@gmail.com    1
mnp@gmail.com    1
Name: date, dtype: int32

df2['status'] = df2['email_id'].str.lower().map(s).fillna(df2['status']).astype(int)
print (df2)
        email_id  status
0  abc@gmail.com       1
1  def@gmail.com       0
2  ghi@gmail.com       1
3  mno@gmail.com       3
4  pqr@gmail.com       2
5  MNP@gmail.com       1
```

Comment: how can i convert the datatype of status from <class 'numpy.int64'> to python standard type int64 ? Can you please help?

Comment: @deepu2711 what is reason? `<class 'numpy.int64'> ` is for Series, `int64`is for value of same Series.

Comment: I need to insert these values to Postgres DB, Please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314929/update-table-values-in-postgres-table-using-psycopg2-in-python?noredirect=1#comment131207069_74314929

Comment: not idea, maybe `int(df2['status'][i])`

Comment: can you please explain how the `s` variable is being created in the solution above, how max() is giving 0,1 status in the df? @jezrael